# Modify values of nested object of different types in a loop

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to loop over all the values of nested objects in Typescript if the nested objects have different types (`a` and `b` below) without resorting to `any`?
I've tried the following

```
const obj = {
    a: {
        foo: 123,
        bar: 456
    },
    b: {
        gg: 789
    }
}

let key: keyof typeof obj
for (key in obj) {
    const subobj = obj[key];
    let subkey: keyof typeof subobj;
    for (subkey in subobj) {
        subobj[subkey] = 100;
    }
}
```

but the typechecker tells me both `subkey` and `subobj` is inferred as `never`

```
The left-hand side of a 'for...in' statement must be of type 'string' or 'any'
let subkey: never
```

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
const subobj: {
    foo: number;
    bar: number;
} | {
    gg: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, I would either

- go for type narrowing - as already proposed by Jay (see also https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or
- try to type the object in question, for example (assuming we are dealing only with 1 nested level of `number`s only) - see snippet below.

Snippet:

```
type Obj = {[subobj: string]: {[subkey:string]: number}}

// obj is now typed
const obj: Obj = {
    a: {
        foo: 123,
        bar: 456
    },
    b: {
        gg: 789
    }
}


// This should work fine now
let key: keyof typeof obj
for (key in obj) {
    const subobj = obj[key];
    let subkey: keyof typeof subobj;
    for (subkey in subobj) {
        subobj[subkey] = 100;
    }
}
```